# Restrict redirection conditionally when URL parameters are changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to restrict certain users from routing to a page 'x' by modifying the URL based on their login credentials. So I am currently able to identify these users but want to restrict page 'x' access only for them. Also, if they try to enter any other parameters then they must get redirected to the current page.

**Example**:

Actual URL
`www.stackoverflow.com`

Modified URL (restricted)
`www.stackoverflow.com/x/`

User must get redirected to 
`www.stackoverflow.com`.

I am using react-router 4
How should I go about this?

Comment: I have worked in angular , and we implement this by guards, But i believe react also has something similar , refer : https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Simply push another route to your router history:

Example supposing the endponint could contain a view accessible to some user and some other users are instead redirected based on ACL:

**In router (where I usually place ACL conditions):**

```
<Route exact path="/myRoute" render={(props) => <MyComponent {...props} mustRedirect={this.myBoolCondition()} />} />
```

**In target MyComponent:**

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.mustRedirect) {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }
```